# Number of view Post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to show Post Number which is being view by the Visitor
e.g

```
  Post 4 of 13 [Previous] [Next]
```

i have counted the total posts in the Category

```
$post_cat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
if($post_cat) {

    $post_cat_id = $post_cat[0]->term_id;
    $cat_posts = get_category($post_cat_id);
    $total_posts = $cat_posts->category_count;
}
```

but problem is i don't get the post number being view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab all posts ( with the same orderby parameter as used in your main query ) and locate the correct position.

```
$all_posts = get_posts( array(
    'category' => $post_cat_id,
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );

$pos = 0;
if ( $all_posts ) foreach ( $all_posts as $all_post ) {
    $pos++;
    if ( $all_post->ID == $post->ID ) break;
}
echo 'position is: ' . $pos;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that what i am looking for .
solve this :)

Comment: Thanks. Looking back on it, running the same query twice does not seem quite right, you should try to combine them. get_posts with a category parameter gives you all the same data ( total_posts would be count( $all_posts ) ), you could use just that and leave out get_category. Although there are likely multiple points of caching - even if WP does not recognize the same query your sql engine will.

Comment: great i was just checking my last posts

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version that I used if there are more than one category in a post. This code will try to use the parent category, if not found, it will use the first child category.

You can also use this with any taxonomy by just setting the taxonomy in the function like this

```
echo get_post_number( $taxonomy = 'my_taxonomy' );
```

Here is the function

```
function get_post_number( $taxonomy = 'category' ) {

        $query_object   = get_queried_object();

        $terms =  wp_get_post_terms( $query_object->ID, $taxonomy ); 

        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if( $term->parent === 0 ) {
                    $parent[] = $term;
                }else{
                    $child[] = $term;
                }
            }       

            if( $parent ) {
                $term_name = $parent[0]->name;
                $term_id   = $parent[0]->term_id;
            }else{
                $term_name = $child[0]->name;
                $term_id   = $child[0]->term_id;
            } 

            $post_args = [ 
                'post_type'         => $query_object->post_type,
                'fields'            => 'ids',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                'tax_query'         => [
                    [
                        'taxonomy'  => $taxonomy,
                        'field'     => 'term_id',
                        'terms'     => $term_id,
                    ],
                ],
            ];

            $q = get_posts( $post_args );

            $total_posts = count( $q );
            $post_number = array_search( $query_object->ID, $q ) + 1;

            $text = 'This is currently post #' . $post_number . ' of ' . $total_posts . ' posted in ' . $term_name;

        }

    return $text;

}
```